# Object property displayed in the console, but returns undefined when I read it

Tags: javascript, node.js

`article` is an object variable.

```
 console.log("reesult id " + JSON.stringify(article));
```

When I do this, it outputs me: `[{"Id":43}]`
and when I do:

```
console.log(article[0]);
```

It outputs me `{"Id":43}`
but now... HOW to get just 43?
Because when I type:

```
console.log(article[0].Id);
```

, It returns me `undefined` instead of `43`. Pf.

**So, HOW to get 43?**

It is very difficult because I made researches and it does not work as well.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle with your code please because like this it looks like everything is fine

Comment: Like @edisoni.1337, I think something is going wrong in another part of your script. Please show the whole script!

Comment: @eoedman1 did you fixed it ?

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to comment to so posting as an answer.
Your solution looks fine.
Could you print the output for

> JSON.stringify(article[0].id)

Comment: It is beause the object is returned by Sequelize (a JS lib to get values object in database)

Comment: I meant , try this : console.log(JSON.stringify(article[0].Id)); In chrome console, the printed value will change if your object is modified at a later stage in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Sequelize has it's own way how to return objects in json so you should try using their way to handle with objects since you are using that library.

This is from Sequelize documentation.

> For any response object that resulted from a query, you can extract
>   only the data you want by appending .get({plain:true}) the the
>   response.

Here you have a [link](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/instances.html#values-of-an-instance) to that documentation so you can read more for that since you are not providing any code to us.